# Which Canon lenses use a B size tripod mount?

Tags: canon, tripod

Which Canon lenses use a B size tripod mount?

Comment: Anyone who downvoted this question, (-1 reps as of now), do you care to explain why? user3709, welcome to the community. Personally, I don't understand what's so wrong with this question. The fact that there are 2 good answers means that the question is valid.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted it, but if I had to take a guess, I'd say that the answer 'why' is probably contained in @Stan's answer... It took him longer to type the answer than it would have taken the OP to simply Google the information...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canon Tripod mount ring types](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3453/canon-tripod-mount-ring-types)

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware of these three:

- **EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM**
- **EF 180mm f/3.5L Macro USM**
- **MP-E 65mm f/2.8 1-5x Macro**

...but that's today, and the answer could have been Googled faster than I can type it.

Comment: Yes Stan, but now your answer is the first result on Google when this question is asked.

Answer (score 1):

well just to start: Canon EF 180mm f3.5L Macro USM, Canon EF 100-400mm f4.5L Macro USM, MP-E 65mm f2.8 1-5x Macro Photo and at least half a dozen others

go to [this site](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/Lens_Advantage_Select) and look around for yourself

Answer (score 0):

These are the Canon lenses which can use "B" tripod rings:
(the "B(W)" or "B(B)" are interchangeable and only differ in color)

- EF 70-200mm 2.8L
- EF 70-200mm 2.8L IS
- EF 70-200mm 2.8L IS II
- EF 100-400L
- EF 100mm 2.8 USM Macro [required adapter is included with B(B)]
- EF 180mm 3.5 Macro,
- EF MP-E 65mm 2.8 Macro